# Find the limit of the sum of product expression $P_n = \sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} \prod_{i = j+1}^n (1-a_i) a_j$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, reference-request, solution-verification

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a convergent sequence, assuming each $1 \geq a_i \geq 0$

consider the series of products

$$P_n = \sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} \prod_{i = j+1}^n (1-a_i) a_j$$

I would like to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n$ or if not possible, find an upperbound to this sequence.

---

**Attempt:**

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} \prod_{i = j+1}^n (1-a_i) a_j \leq \sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} \prod_{i = 1}^n (1-a_i) a_j$$

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) says $\prod_{i = 1}^n (1-a_i) \leq \exp\left(-\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i\right)$

So

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} \prod_{i = j+1}^n (1-a_i) a_j \leq \exp(-\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i) \sum_{j = 1}^{n-1}  a_j$$

Then the upperbound to this limit is $$\exp\left(-\lim_{i = 1}^n \sum_{i = 1}^n  a_i\right) \cdot\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} a_j.$$

Is this correct? An alternative approach uses the AM-GM inequality on the inner product term.

Comment: Does the product apply to just $(1-a_i)$ or to $(1-a_i)a_j$? IE $\prod_{i=2}^3 \left[ ( 1 - a_i) a_1 \right] = (1-a_2)a_1(1-a_3)a_1$.

Comment: @CalvinLin According to his attempt, I think it is $P_n = \sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} a_j\prod_{i = j+1}^n (1-a_i)$. According to Le p'tit bonhomme's answer, it is equal to $1-a_n-\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can easily prove by induction that:
$$P_n=1-a_n-\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i).$$

In the case where the limit $\lim_{i\to+\infty} a_i=\alpha>0$, the product tends to $0$ and
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} P_n=1-\alpha.$$
(Indeed, one can find a geometric upperbound of the product.)

In the case where the limit $\lim_{i\to+\infty} a_i=0$, the sequence of the products $\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)$ is non negative and non increasing, so it converges to some $\beta\in[0,1]$ and then
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} P_n=1-\beta.$$

Some extreme exemples:

--$a_i=0$ implies $\beta=1$.

--$a_i=\frac 1{i+1}$ implies $\beta=0$.